# Python code of explicit method of a nonlinear a BVP

Tags: python, finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, nonlinear-programming, explicit-methods

I am trying to have a Python code for the following nonlinear BVP:
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 N}{\partial x^2}+N(1-N)-\sigma N$$  $$N(0,x)=\sin(2\pi x)$$
$$N(t,0)=0 \hspace{3mm}N(t,L)=0 \hspace{1.5mm};\hspace{2mm}t>0,0<x<L.$$

Without the non-linear part I discretize with explicit FTCS method.
$$\frac{N_{i,j+1}-N_{i,j}}{k} = c^2\frac{N_{i+1,j}-2N_{i,j}+N_{i-1,j}}{h^2}$$
$$N_{i,j+1} = \lambda[N_{i+1,j}-2N_{i,j}+_{i-1,j}]+N_{i,j}$$
$$\text{where}\hspace{3mm} \lambda = \frac{c^2k}{h^2} $$

But the problem is that maybe I can't discretize the nonlinear part. That's why my Python code does not respond well and I am new to Python. So, can anybody help me with a Python algorithm?

Comment: Please describe in sufficient detail how you would discretize if the non-linear part were absent.

Comment: I am sorry .I just edited the post. @LutzLehmann

Comment: What specifically is it that prevents you from "discretiz[ing] the nonlinear part?

Comment: because I dont understand that do I have to discretize the system of  linear ODE from this  PDE or I should just discretize the whole PDE. @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a lot of background on the construction of finite difference schemes, explicit vs implicit time stepping schemes, etc. Have you taken a look at a book about finite difference methods?

Comment: No.I am trying to solve a random problem given by someone. and yes I know that I am missing a huge part about it.thanks for getting the point.  can you suggest me a book ?@WolfgangBangerth

Comment: *Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations: Steady-State and Time-dependent Problems* by Randall LeVeque is a great reference. If you are familiar with using numerical ODE solvers in Python (`scipy.integrate` for instance) then you can forego the need to really understand the time-stepping for a nonlinear problem via the Method of Lines, where you just discretize in space then solve the resulting system of ODEs using an arbitrary method of your choice.